# how to run a kubernetes cronjob with modified values at runtime

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-cronjob

So I have a kubernetes cronjob object set to run periodically.

```py
NAME                            SCHEDULE       SUSPEND   ACTIVE   LAST SCHEDULE   AGE
ticketing-job-lifetime-manager  45 */4 * * *   False     0        174m            25d
```

and I know how to call it manually:

```yaml
# ticketing-job-manual-call will be the name of the job that runs
kubectl create job --from=cronjobs/ticketing-job-lifetime-manager ticketing-job-manual-call
```

**BUT** - what I want to do is call the job, but modify portions of it (shown below) before it is called.  Specifically `items.metadata.annotations` and `items.spec.jobTemplate.spec.containers.args`.

If this is possible on-the-fly, I'd be over the moon.  If it requires creating a temporary object, then I'd appreciate an approach to doing this that is robust, performant - and safe.  Thanks!

```yaml
    apiVersion: v1
    items:
      - apiVersion: batch/v1
        kind: CronJob
        metadata:
          annotations:
            <annotation-1>              <- want to modify these
            <annotation-2>
            ..
            <annotation-n>
          creationTimestamp: "2022-05-03T13:24:49Z"
          labels:
            AccountID: foo
            FooServiceAction: "true"
            FooServiceManaged: "true"
            CronName: foo
          name: foo
          namespace: my-namespace
          resourceVersion: "298013999"
          uid: 57b2-4612-88ef-a0d5e26c8
        spec:
          concurrencyPolicy: Replace
          jobTemplate:
            metadata:
              annotations:
                <annotation-1>          <- want to modify these
                <annotation-2>
                ..
                <annotation-n>
              creationTimestamp: null
              labels:
                AccountID: 7761777c38d93b
                TicketServiceAction: "true"
                TicketServiceManaged: "true"
                CronName: ticketing-actions-7761777c38d93b-0
              name: ticketing-actions-7761777c38d93b-0
              namespace: rias
            spec:
              containers:
                - args:
                    - --accountid=something     <- want to modify these
                    - --faultzone=something
                    - --type=something
                    - --cronjobname=something
                    - --plans=something
                  command:
                    - ./ticketing-job
                  env:
                    - name: FOO_BAR             <- may want to modify these
                      value: "false"
                    - name: FOO_BAZ
                      value: "true"
```

Comment: Annotation can be overriden with , kubectl annotate command. check the options 'kubectl annotate --help' .  For env variable, not clear with use case, but still  you can use dependent Environment variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to think about this is that Kubernetes resources are defined (definitively) by YAML|JSON config files. A useful advantage to having config files is that these can be checked into source control; you automatically audit your work if you create unique files for each resource (for every change).

Kubernetes (`kubectl`) isn't optimized|designed to tweak Resources although you can use [`kubectl patch`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/update-api-object-kubectl-patch/) to update deployed Resources.

I encourage you to consider a better approach that is applicable to any Kubernetes resource (not just `Job`'s) and this focuses on use YAML|JSON files as the way to represent state:

1. `kubectl get` the resource and output it as YAML|JSON (`--output=json|yaml`) persisting the result to a file (that could be source-controlled)
2. Mutate the file using any of many tools but preferably YAML|JSON processing tools (e.g. [`yq`](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) or [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/))
3. `kubectl create` or `kubectl apply` the file that results that reflects the intended configuration of the new resource.

By way of example, assuming you use `jq`:

```sh
# Output 'ticketing-job-lifetime-manage' as a JSON file
kubectl get job/ticketing-job-lifetime-manage \
--namespace=${NAMESPACE} \
--output=json > ${PWD}/ticketing-job-lifetime-manage.json

# E.g. replace '.metadata.annotations' entirely
jq '.metadata.annotations=[{"foo":"x"},{"bar":"y"}]' \
${PWD}/${PWD}/ticketing-job-lifetime-manage.json \
> ${PWD}/${PWD}/new-job.json

# E.g. replace a specific container 'foo' specific 'args' key with value
jq '.spec.jobTemplate.spec.containers[]|select(.name=="foo").args["--key"]="value" \
${PWD}/${PWD}/new-job.json \
> ${PWD}/${PWD}/new-job.json

# Etc.

# Apply
kubectl create \
--filename=${PWD}/new-job.json \
--namespace=${NAMESPACE}
```

> **NOTE** You can pipe the output from the `kubectl get` through `jq` and into `kubectl create` if you wish but it's useful to keep a file-based record of the resource.

Having to deal with YAML|JSON config file is a common issue with Kubernetes (and every other technology that uses them). There are other tools e.g. [jsonnet](https://jsonnet.org/) and [CUE](https://cuelang.org/docs/integrations/k8s/) that try to provide a more programmatic way to manage YAML|JSON.

Comment: Thanks, this gives me the sense that I'm pretty close to understanding the essential way Kubernetes works (and that there are no magic bullets either).  This is doable, I have the coding skills with json/python etc. - just wanted to make sure I wasn't re-inventing the wheel

Comment: You're welcome! Good luck!

Comment: Ironically, after responding last night, I read an article this morning about [Kustomize](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/kustomization/). I have not used it but it appears to another way to solve the problems outlined above.

Comment: The original question was how to modify values of a cronjob and run it as a job. `kubectl get job` doesn't get you there because the target is a cronjob. You would use `kubectl create job --from cronjob-name --dry-run=client --output=json > output.json`